# Why can't I accept an answer in the first 15 minutes after asking the question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have just noticed there is a short time span of 15 minutes after asking a question when you cannot accept an answer.

I'm really curious why it does so, because I can't think of a reason for having it...

Comment: There was a tendency for people to accept the first correct answer and never change it. This gives a chance for better answers to arrive

Comment: Reflection time.

Comment: I also guess that, if a question is so easy and straightforward to be answered so shortly, and yet you have asked it, there is a strong chance that you've made no prior reasearch at all.

Comment: Remember that this site is about building a good Q&A database, and as such it may take a while for some good answers to be written, that go well beyond the point you tried to get answered, but are really useful for people visiting your question

Comment: @RichardTingle But this might also increase the number of questions with no accepted answers if the answer that comes in in the first 10 minutes answers the person's question and he never comes back to accept the answer.

Comment: From where did the number 10 minutes come? Is it some random number or something statistically based?

Comment: I wonder if this should now be moved to MSE instead?

Comment: I can see the necessity to take time to review an answer, but why 10? Where did this number come from?

Comment: @RanaPrathap: it is actually *15* minutes. But the timer counts down, and if you clicked the 'accept' mark after 5, you are told to wait another 10.

Comment: @Jack: this has been discussed on MSE many times over.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so does that mean it should be here or there? Or neither?

Comment: @Jack: no, we can discuss this here just fine. Moving it to MSE would be pointless however, now we have a dupe target *here* for all the repeats that do crop up here too.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

According to [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately) the motivation, [as stated by](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75200/161198) [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), is the following:

> It is our strong belief that if you accept an answer in less than 15 minutes after asking the question, you have not given the community an adequate chance to fully answer your question before rushing to accept.

Comment: If the answer does actually answer the question, then that's all that matters. "Not giving enough time" is very subjective - if an answer is good enough to accept that means it had enough time. I'd wait an hour, a month, even a year for a good answer, but if one comes in 2 minutes - then all the better. Also, a little hypocritical considering all the questions getting closed in racing for merit points without giving any "timeout" whatsoever or chance to be answered, often interrupting people typing answers in the process.

Comment: @user2341104 I have had the experience a few times where I was writing a more detailed answer that addressed underlying issues or did a bit of outlining a process for solving the same problem in the future. Things which go a little beyond simply fixing the problem. But I end up getting beat by someone who had a 2 line response saying to dereference a point by adding a * at a particular line. It solves that problem, so it seems reasonable to accept, but my answer had the same solution but would have done a lot more to help others in the future, but took too long to write.

Comment: @Justin What some people seem to do is first write the quick answer (to win an initial race for up votes), then edit it to be more complete. This doesn't seem like perfect behavior, but perhaps that's another question.

Comment: @Justin although it doesn't happen often, it is possible to change the accepted answer.

Comment: @user2341104: Question: "How do I make a pot of coffee?". Answer 1, 45 seconds after asking: "Put the beans in the machine. Press go." Answer 2, 3 hours later: "Take the beans out of the bag, grind them on fine using the GrindMaster 3000 (no one wants coarse ground, obviously), Put them in a conical filter and put it into your machine. Fill it with water and press go.". See where I'm going with this?

Comment: @Brandon "This question is off-topic because it in no way relates to programming" ;)

Comment: @Bart Coffee is ALWAYS related to programming XD

Comment: It also gives chance for good answer to collect upvotes. I noticed people tend to avoid looking at questions with already accepted answers.

Answer (score 102):

because if you give time, the audience can write a complete answer. I guess that one of the reasons behind this constraint is to keep the quality of the answers high

Comment: I think this should have been the answer. Too late now.

Comment: Yeah, if they had changed the delay from 10 minutes to 3 hours, your answer may have been chosen as "the answer". :)

Comment: Nice humor :-) At least on SO, it's never "too late" for the OP to reconsider the accepted answer (I suppose meta also allows that).

Comment: I... Well, it IS a good answer...

Comment: But on the other hand, Bart's answer is good too. Plus, removing the checkmark and giving it to someone else because they had a good answer too feels, well, wrong to me.

Comment: Don't feel bad if you give the checkmark to someone else after you already accpted an answer if the other answer is clearly better. Accepting an answer is not a personal thing. We aren't going to search you and have a "deep talk" about your decision. Quality should take precedence here.

Comment: Yes, well, the community seems to prefer the already accepted answer more. I think I'll stick with Bart.

Comment: Do note that I even though I accepted Bart's answer, I also liked Daniele's answer, so I up-voted it.

Comment: I think that is exactly the point Toby. Many of the times I look at answers that has more upvotes- sometimes because it is better and many of the times because it is current to the latest release

Answer (score 35):

The way I look at it is, what's the rush?  Is there an argument in support of a speedy verdict?  I'm not aware of any.  There is the obvious downside that a rush to judgment may discourage other, potentially better answers, but there's another consideration that hasn't been mentioned: it is disrespectful, in my opinion, to those still preparing answers.

I expect most of us have had the experience of reading a question a few minutes after it was posted, started work on a killer solution, only to see the green checkmark flash on out of the corner of our eye.  It's one thing when this happens, say, an hour after the question was posted--you take your chances--but when it happens a mere 15 minutes after the question was posted, now that's annoying.  In effect, the asker is saying, "I've got what I wanted, which is all I care about, so I'm 'outa here".  (OK, sometimes it's a SO newbie who hasn't taken the time to find out how the forum works.)

I'd like to see the minimum wait for choosing an answer raised, not lowered.

Comment: If the minimum wait time was raised, you'd see lots of questions without accepted answers as most people's attention span is quite short.

Comment: @soulcheck, where I spend my time on SO, the vast majority of answer selections are not made quickly, so I don't think that would be a major factor.  I can't say for other SE locales.  I think there is much that could be done to encourage askers to make selections, however, such as presenting first-time askers with a checklist of things they need to do or think about, and an email follow-up from SO to askers, when no answer has been selected after a couple of days, containing a gentle nudge.

Comment: "I've got what I wanted" - once that happens they're outta here anyway, whether they had the chance to accept an answer or not. All you're doing is depriving them of the opportunity to give useful feedback.

Comment: @Cary: Checklists on the website itself will just be ignored but the email is a _very_ good idea.

Answer (score 10):

The idea that the OP gets to accept one answer is already half flawed because the OP is often the *least* qualified person to determine the best solution to their problem.

The ten minute period allows the experts some time to present the various options and solutions, so that at least the OP can make *some* kind of informed decision before concluding that answer X is the one he/she/it wishes to use and mark as superlative.

Comment: I think accepted answers are a valuable feedback channel; it communicates to future readers what worked best for the OP. It may not be the highest quality answer, but upvotes are more than capable of performing that function.

Comment: @Brad: That's why I said "half flawed" not "fundamentally flawed" or "useless" :)

Comment: *`because the OP is often the least qualified person to determine the best solution to their problem`* [sooo true!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263489/array-declaration-issue-with-csharp/)

Comment: I completely agree with you (and @mehow) that the OP is almost by definition not the person qualified to accept an answer - yet that is how all of SE works. The delay before they can accept increases the window during which some good answers can appear (and be upvoted). An imperfect system, whichever way you spin it. But it's the one we have.

Comment: @Floris: Right, which is exactly what my answer says!

Comment: Lightness, further to your point, increasing the delay also gives more time for members to point out weaknesses or errors in the solution the OP would have chosen had there not been enforced delay. How many times have you seen an OP make a quick-draw selection of the first answer posted, only for members to later show the answer was incorrect. Sometimes the OP withdraws the checkmark (though newbie OP's often don't know they can do that), other times they don't, possibly never learning that their coveted answer, which they may have implemented, was flawed.