# Correlation between reputation and response acceptance

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, new-users

It seems to me that most users with low reputation will accept answers in the comments with "That's it!" or "It worked, thanks!" but will not mark the answer as accepted -maybe because they are unaware on how the site works - while more seasoned users will mark when the answer is appropriate.

So, is there any statistical evidence or actual case studies that correlate the reputation a user has and the willingness to mark an answer as accepted?

Comment: Heh.  I just got one of these an hour ago.  I imagine that if you yourself have ever answered a single question, the acceptance rate on questions you ask is much higher (since you presumably understand better how the website works).

Comment: I don't think you really need the stats since this is obviously true. Almost every new user has trouble with this. Using a comment I often explain them the importance of voting / marking as answer and ask them to review their previous questions too. This often helps.

Comment: More Reputation = More Time on the Site = Understanding more of how the site works = Accepting answers to your questions. I know there was a time when I bothered to go search for my unanswered questions and marked a bunch as accepted. The time wasn't related to my rep, it was related to my knowledge of the site.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is not obviously true without the stats to back it up. It is only anecdotal :-)

Comment: I have a relatively low rate of marking answers "accepted", primarily because the questions I ask are often too hard to draw a valid response.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks for your efforts but even with them my impression is that a considerable part of users just pose one question take away the answer (or you never know if it was a helpful answer) and never come back at all. Maybe we can draw them a diagram next to the question. Anything that helps increase the acceptance rate a bit.

Comment: @Trilarion: I am afraid that despite how many effort is made, this at most will help a bit. Did you really read the beautiful interactive Getting Started? I doubt 99% of the new users did (I am sure since there is a badge for it).

Comment: @PatrickHofman You're right. There might not be much hope. But still seeing that not many people visit the about page we could take it as a sign to more prominently refer to it (during registration, when asking your first question, ..) and remind people on unmarked questions, ..

Comment: @Trilarion: good point. If you want to, create a feature request for it. I will support it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Okay I will but probably only in the next days. I want to do it right and make some mockups how it could lock.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Oh I will just go through the process of a newbie registering and creating his first question and I will ask myself how to best refer to the about page and in which form. Cannot say now where and how this will be. I will just propose a bunch of things I think are possible and then you guys pick what you like.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is significant correlation.

Questions asked by users with at most 100 rep have accepted answer in [40% of cases](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194641/accept-rate-in-rep-range?minReputation=0&maxReputation=100).

In case of users who have at least 100 rep this rate [raises to 70%](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194641/accept-rate-in-rep-range?minReputation=100&maxReputation=999999999999):

Following plot shows in detail how accept rate raises for low rep users. They are grouped in buckets of 5 rep points to avoid periodic noise (if your rep is `1 + 5k` it's likely that you never accepted an answer).
[image: Accept rate by rep graph]

Comment: Something looks wrong with the linked queries; the URLs encode min/max values but only the max value is used.  eg the second returns results starting at 0 just like the first one does.

Comment: @DanNeely, it seems I accidentally overrode the old query when adding graph. It should work now.

Comment: I think this approach conflates the question we're trying to answer - "what percentage of correctly-answered questions are not marked as answered by new users because they don't understand how the website works" with the fact that new users more frequently post bad/really bad/unanswerable questions that get closed.

Comment: @roippi, adding condition `AnswerCount > 0` doesn't change much (other than moving graph up a few percent points). I think the result is quite robust.

Comment: Even when limiting to non-closed questions with upvoted answers low-rep users are still less likely to accept. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194725/accept-rate-by-rep-only-questions-with-good-answers?maxReputation=200#graph

Comment: What about users who have only posted one question vs. users who have posted at least two?

Answer (score 6):

Before we build a [Data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/), let's find out whether we're asking the right question:

- Are this really low-reputation users who do not accept answers? What
  does low reputation mean? How low?
- Might it depend less on the
  reputation but on the number of questions a user has already asked?
  Maybe it was a good question, got many upvotes, but it is still the
  only question of that user.
- Is StackOverflow simply responding too
  fast so that a newbie gets an answer, tries to accept but the [10
  minutes period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-10-minutes-after-asking-the-question?rq=1) is not over yet?
- Does it also depend on the fact that
  a newbie has never given an answer and not experienced that not
  becoming the accepted answer makes it hard to get required
  privileges?
- Does it also depend on whether or not they have read the
  tour and earned the `Informed` badge?

With all the questions open, this is a first graph which might help the discussion:
[Find unanswered questions by noob and reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194618/find-unanswered-questions-by-noob-and-reputation?MaxRep=40#graph)

[image: Screenshot of the query result]

We can see the spikes at 1, 6 and 11 which are due to the 5 point reputation change per upvote. And we can see the number decreasing, which was expected.

Since I am new to OData, I make this a community wiki answer, so anyone can contribute here.

Comment: “And we can see the number decreasing” Isn't that just because the number of users decreases with increasing reputation?

Comment: @svick, or they're more engaged with the site, know how it works and accept an answer.

Comment: We could also argue to remove questions younger than 2 days, because the OP is still waiting for other answers.

Comment: @svick: Agreed, but what is a good proposal to have a better graph? Use percentage instead? I don't think that will help much. I think using reputation as one axis is not very good. I'd like to see a graph with number of questions on x-axis.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, I see the advantage of *"forcing function that requires they accept an answer on their first question before being allowed to ask a second." --msw*.

*I feels odd making a suggestion on this topic, having never posted a question myself...*

Another idea...

For users who have earned a reputation under a specific threshold (say, 15; referencing Thomas W.' s graph).  Find a way that might compel them to return to their question, after a time, and take some sort of action (loosely defined below).

If the hypothetical action is taken, the user would be free to ask another question immediately.

Otherwise, if the user attempts to post a new question, the system might inform the user of all previous previous questions that have been posted by the user, where the hypothetical action has not been taken; and that until taking the hypothetical action, the user is dis-allowed from posting new questions.

The 'hypothetical action(s)' include:

- Accepting a suitable answer (of course).
- Pressing a "No suitable answer yet" [NSAY] button.

When the [NSAY] button is pushed; it would show a timer that counts down until the button needs to be pushed again.  Perhaps the timer's expiration period would get progressively longer each time it is pressed.  Again referencing the graphs posted by *Thomas W.* and *zch*, perhaps the timer would first expire after 5-10 minutes (while the user is hopefully still present active at SO).  When pressed next, the timer might expire after 8 hours, then perhaps 24 hours.

After pressing the [NSAY] button, it would become non-operational (grayed-out) until it expires. (Of course, it would not affect the users ability to accept an answer any time).

This [NSAY] button would be non-operational (grayed-out) permanently when the user has accepted an answer.

---

What behavior is best for low-rep question users?  If it is that they should return periodically and review the answers; then perhaps something like a [NSAY] button would train them to do that. As their reputation improves, this "conditioning" would be eliminated. (Although it does taste like *The Button* on the TV show 'Lost').

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to require the user to keep pushing the button repeatedly if there has been no new activity (new answers, comments, edits) on the post.  Also, I wonder how many of the users who haven't accepted an answer yet have posted more than one question?

Comment: Both good points @HarryJohnston.  Perhaps the user should perceptive no correlation between the button and answering questions (if the purpose is to elicite a specific behavior (of checking back on their questions to see if a a suitable answer exists.  Perhaps the timer wouldn't really start (or expire) until answers have been posted, or edited.  As for your last question, I have wondered the same thing.  In reality, users could side step all this effort by creating a new account for each new question.

Comment: 10 minutes is an absurdly short time-out for low volume tags. The time-outs should _start_ at 24hrs.

Comment: @tcaswell, sure; 24hrs works for me.  However, considering a 'newbie' session; the user may ask the question, wait a few minutes for an answer, and then go off and explore SO a little more.  At this point, would we want the user to go back to their question and view the comments... and perhaps examine answers?  I'm just looking for a way to instill the desired behavior. (And I worry that after 24 hours, the user may have lost interest in their earlier question.)  For me, it is important that the user return to their question prior to leaving the site.