# Show OP engagement history statistics on questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, user-interface, statistics

### Motivation

It is a frequent occurrence on SO that OPs do not engage with the responses they get. They do not vote, do not accept and do not comment on any of the sometimes multiple answers they receive. This is frustrating to respondents, because, after having invested time and effort into writing up an answer to help them, the OP is not even willing to spend what little time it takes to engage with the answer and give them feedback whether the answer was helpful. Some of the people behaving this way just ask one question and never return. But others are repeat offenders at this.

This frustration has led to many asking for mods or the community to be able to vote to set an answer as accepted (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262672/can-moderators-make-an-answer-accepted-to-close-the-post)) or to punish the users (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255735/should-people-who-show-a-lack-of-engagement-with-their-own-questions-be-penalize)). There are good reasons why these have not been implemented. Yet, it remains a problem that lack of engagement is a drag on the motivation of people providing answers on SO.

### Proposal

I think questions should show statistics about OP's past engagement with answers they received for their questions. What share of the answers they receive do they vote on? For how many of their questions that received an answer did they accept one? With how many of the answers they received did they engage at all?

If we had statistics like that, clearly visible next to the question, people who care about getting engagement from OPs can just avoid answering questions by the repeat offenders of non-engagement. It might also encourage the repeat offenders to change their behavior in order to increase their likelihood of getting an answer.  Given the extent to which [acceptance behavior correlates to reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255159/11932936) and by extension experience, it makes sense to educate less experienced users on this matter.

### Possible Downsides

- This might lead to people accepting answers that did not solve the problem. This is a valid concern that could be addressed by only showing this number when it is particularly low.
- It might lead to OPs upvoting undeserving answers. I think this is not much of a problem, as any answer that shows a serious effort by the respondent deserves an upvote from the OP even if it did not fully solve the problem. Downvotes cost reputation and not everyone can downvote, but the cost is low, as is the reputation threshold. Also, low-quality answers where no good faith effort was made are not that common.
- To some who do not care about this information, this might be clutter. The three statistics I suggested are just a proposal, I would already find just one of them fairly helpful. If clutter is an issue, then maybe just go with one or two.

### Alternatives

I have cited some unsuccessful past proposals for dealing with non-engagement with answers. Another way to encourage engagement would be notifications or other prompts to call users attention to these questions and animate them to engage. I have no idea to what extent this might already be happening, as I rarely ask questions and do engage with answers that I receive. But if it does not exist, that would also be a measure I would like to see.

### tl;dr

Show stats on OP's answer engagement history next to their questions.

Comment: As I understand it: In the relatively early days of the site, statistics about a user's rate of accepting answers to their questions used to be shown. Showing that rate was, eventually, deemed detrimental to the overall function of the site, so they were removed. I strongly doubt that has changed. Thus, I consider it unlikely that SE will choose to display such metrics for users.

Comment: This was a thing, and was indeed removed. It promoted toxic behaviour.

Comment: To be fair, your voting ratio for questions you've answered doesn't seem to be that good as well (at least for the latest questions you've answered). So, not only some OPs but answerers could also get negative feedback from such a feature.

Comment: Counterproposal: we should hide all information about the author of the question from users with less than 10k.

Comment: Not sure why this is so downvoted but that's right I'm unlikely to post an answer that won't be even read by the OP. While it's true that answers are for helping all people, still the OP is an important one. If the OP isn't important therefore the accept answers feature should be removed altogether. Maybe we shouldn't show that this user has bad metrics, but at least we should prevent those users from asking new questions. if they don't bother to read the answers, they shouldn't be allowed to ask more.

Comment: I agree, the feature to accept answers should be removed.

Comment: Well, the Data you want is already available actually, from the 'Activity' Tab on a User's Profile, [here is yours](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11932936/shs?tab=topactivity) for example @OP... (+ Link on "View all xxx questions" if the User has more than 5 questions...)

Comment: @chivracq I don't see the summary statistics that I proposed be shown. I can get an impression of the acceptance rate, but not on overall engagement or voting behavior, at least as far as I can see. Besides, this is so buried, that no one will use it to gauge the engagement behavior of an OP when deciding if they want to answer a question

Comment: @shs, "*Besides, this is so buried, that no one will use it to gauge the engagement behavior of an OP when deciding if they want to answer a question.*", well..., I do...!, always...! // Mostly [1-Rep + 1st Qt] Users in the small Tag I answer, but if they already have say 3+ Qt's and none with an accepted Answer, then I go and check their Qt's on the "Follow-up", same with Askers with already say 10 Qt's and [0-2] accepted Answer, then I check a few of their "other" Qt's to check the Follow-up on any Comments or Answers, ... and if no Follow-up, I won't bother answering their Qt... Simple...!

Comment: @chivracq As far as I am aware both are valid, just with different effects. Which is also what is said at the [bottom of this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/435266/what-does-tldr-mean-and-how-do-you-use-it/). Btw, I also find the headers somewhat large, but it appears to be a conscious design choice by SO devs to render level 1 markdown headers so large. Maybe a topic for another meta post?

Comment: Ah...!?, hum..., OK... Qt now closed as a Duplicate, but I find the [Dupe Target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368391/3799241) of very low Quality (maybe 10 Typos in just 2 Lines in the Qt), and both the Qt and the only Answer are full of "Drama Queen" Rhetoric... Ex: "*You're making the site worse by not providing useful information*"...

Comment: "any answer that shows a serious effort by the respondent deserves an upvote from the OP even if it did not fully solve the problem." I find that not expecting upvotes out of duty but rather quality automatically dismisses the worst (or even all ) effects of disinterested OPs. It’s a strategy wholeheartedly recommend.

Comment: We wouldn't be able to get useful stats anyway, I expect, because most (or at least a substantial percentage of) questions asked on the site are the user's first question.

Comment: The "trick" is to answer questions which are likely to have utility beyond the OP. Such answers should accrue "engagement" (votes) over a long period of time. This fits nicely with SO being  a site about questions and answers that stand on their own merits, regardless of the motivations or actions of their original posters.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I love how one of the major reasons not to have engagement statistics is the fear that fewer questions will receive answers. And then people say, hey why don't you avoid the frustration of non-engagement from OPs by answering fewer questions. This is my whole point. Non-engagement from OPs leads to fewer questions being answered overall.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you can recognize first timers based on their reputation and adjust your expectations accordingly. You can't do that with repeat non-engagers. It is not even that rare to see bountied questions receive 3 good answers and no engagement, no award from OP

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My point wasn't that I was necessarily expecting that kind of voting behavior on answers I give. I prefer a downvote with a good explanation comment over no engagement at all. My point was that excessive upvoting is a negligible potential downside from having voting rates reported. Also, even good quality answers regularly receive no engagement from OPs

Comment: @shs You misunderstand me. I'm saying avoid the frustration on non-engagement by OPs by decoupling your actions from theirs. The target audience for answers is ultimately future visitors who find them through search, not the OP.

Comment: @shs My point is that for high quality content, the engagement rate of the OP does not matter. If the OP is the only one capable and interested in rating answers - and thus is expected/needed to do so - that is a good sign for low-quality Q&A.

Answer (score 17):

This is a terrible idea.

This would give people the impression that we are here to help only OP. Stack Overflow would turn into a help desk rather than being Q&A.

Showing this kind of information could also cause certain users to stop interacting with questions from users with poor stats. This would be bad for the site as it would limit the number of potential answers.

Also, questions with accepted answers would see fewer alternative answers as users would not see the incentive to post answers when there's already an accepted answer. This already happens now, but it would only be exacerbated by the site putting more emphasis on accept votes.

And primarily, as history has shown us, these statistics lead to toxic and vile behaviour. Users willing to do anything to get reputation would hunt and harass people to upvote/accept more. They could even start downvoting based on user's statistics rather than the merits of the post. Nothing good could come out of this.

You listed disadvantages, but I do not see any advantages. All it would do is bad stuff for the site. It would put more focus on the person rather than the question.

I would like to point out that OP is under no obligation to accept any answer. This is completely optional. This feature exists only to allow OP to select their preferred answer if they want to. **It should never be the goal when posting answers!**

Comment: It's true that the OP isn't forced to accept an answer but at least they *should* interact with their question. If I write an answer that didn't work they should mention that (and downvote my answer if possible). If I write an answer that needs more details, they should ask for details. But some people don't really bother to do anything.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Maybe they didn't see any need to interact? Maybe they are still waiting for better answers? Maybe there's nothing wrong with the existing answer and no need to downvote?

Comment: What if they repeat that with every question they ask? Is that considered OK?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: The OP is only required to interact with the comments asking clarifications, by means of editing their question. Everything else is optional.

Comment: There is a difference between what is required and what is considered good behavior and what should be encouraged. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is clearly encouraging to vote on any answer and accept those that represent the best solution. You are acting as though expecting either is offensive.

Comment: It's quite obvious that we expect people with upvoting privileges to use them on *answers they find helpful*, but we should not be asking them for upvotes, pushing them to upvote any answer, or discriminating against them based on their voting habits. These actions would be offensive. Just because I don't want to upvote or accept any answers to my question doesn't mean I am a bad contributor to the site.

Comment: By that logic the whole reputation system is offensive. It is pushing people to do all kinds of things. Of course, incentives can have unintended, negative consequences. Those just need to be weighed against the benefits. That does not mean incentive systems are fundamentally offensive

Comment: @shs: *"...pushing people to do all kinds of things"*: Yes, including posting answers to blatant duplicates instead of voting to close.

Comment: "By that logic the whole reputation system is offensive." It's terribly designed in many ways, and I have complained about them before a fair bit, so yes.

Answer (score 7):

After having been made aware of the previous existence of the acceptance rate feature, I looked into [why it was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate). Apparently, some people like to [ask to bring it back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368391/bring-back-acceptance-rate/368392#368392). But that is not going to happen. The debate has been settled. There seem to be two major deciding arguments.

First, it will reduce the propensity of users to post answers to questions by low-engagement OPs, depriving the community of the value of those answers. I disagree here, because the frustrating experience of not getting engagement will make people less likely to post answers in the future.

Second, the old feature led to toxic behavior by some members of the community. Some examples can be found in the [old meta se issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) and I do agree that it is problematic.

The acceptance rate was not what I was mostly looking for in my question, as I had already acknowledged potential problems with this particular metric. Yet, I feel that the two major reasons for the removal would also apply to other engagement statistics.

Prior to writing this question, I mostly looked at previous discussions about "engagement" and had not done a search on "acceptance rate". If I had been aware of the discourse around the acceptance rate, then I would not have posted this question. I thought about deleting it, but I think keeping it has value for anyone in the future looking for why there are no engagement statistics provided. Thus, I have just voted to close it as a duplicate of an old attempt to bring back the acceptance rate.

Comment: "*because the frustrating experience of not getting engagement will make people less likely to post answers in the future.*", yep, exactly...! You call it "engagement", I call it "Follow-up" as I come from a "(Tech) Forum Culture" with some "Internet/Forum Etiquette" where Users have to "follow up" when they have a *Problem* and are asking for Help, and I will usually not help them/answer their Qt anymore before they finished their previous Thread(s) "neatly" and "useful for the Community", ... unless their Scenario/Qt is very "unique" and has never been answered/solved before...