# Should you self-answer immediately or wait a bit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, self-answer, instant-self-answer

After the release of Swift 3, I have seen many top users here posting questions like API changes to prevent duplicate questions. I know its one of the best way to prevent flood of questions in the same topic.

In tea time,we had a conversation while one of my colleague find it as
a great way to post a question and answering by ownself and make Search Engine help him to increase reputation.

So, my questions are:

1. What if he posts about the changes of different question and answer them following SO guidelines?
2. Is that acceptable?

Certainly I wouldn't be happy to see his question and answer about the changes. And may be search engine would show his question at top and other users may find the same.

I don't find it a good way. Posting a question and answering it within seconds. I know this way helps community a better way. But certainly that doesn't seems fair on SEO and reputation points.

I think it should be the other way around. Can't answer your own questions for like about 15 minutes/ half an hour.

P.S: I am not against of posting the answers by own. I have given answer to some of my questions but not like seconds of posting it.

Comment: If it was unfair, there wouldn't be a "self-answer" checkbox on the ask a question page.

Comment: i am saying its good to answer ..but not like in seconds...may be half an hour...or some minutes

Comment: This kind of behaviour is not acceptable, it's **encouraged**.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-15-minutes-after-asking-the-question

Comment: Right, and the self answer checkbox allows you to answer **immediately**, there's nothing wrong with posting a self-answered question. Just keep in mind that it will still have to follow all of the usual question and answer guidelines.

Comment: @KevinB And he's proposing that that be changed to not function that way.  He's not asking *if* he can answer immediately, he's asserting that people shouldn't be allowed to.

Comment: Ah,  i'm mis-interpreting the question entirely then?

Comment: If someone has a good question _and_ a great answer for it, then they deserve any rep they gain from it - they've done us all a favor by sharing their knowledge.

Comment: @Mat That makes sense But thats not i am trying to infer...With release of swift 3..people are documenting some small changes in SO...and thats not a good reason to share it??

Comment: If the question or answer is not useful or not a good fit for SO, downvote/vote to close as usual. If it is, what are you complaining about?

Comment: well i just don't find it fair to post questions and answers about some simple API changes with the release of swift 3...

Comment: Ignore whether or not you think it's fair, and instead decide whether or not it is useful to you or the community because that's something you can act upon. There's no action that you can take on a question/answer due to fairness, but you can vote on quality.

Comment: @anishparajuli If you feel that a given question is a low quality quesiton, irrespective of the fact that it was self answered (or when), then vote accordingly.  If you feel an answer is a low quality answer, irrespective of the fact that the answerer is the author of the quesiton, then vote accordingly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's disingenuous to *wait* if you already know the answer when posting a question.  Others that might be inclined to post the same solution, or an inferior solution, would be spending time writing an answer that isn't going to be helpful, all because someone is intentionally withholding a better answer.  At *best* these people are now just wasting time, at worst people actually end up using the inferior answers that get posted.

Preventing self-answers for a period of time would be *harmful*, not *helpful*.

Comment: you are correct...But people should not be allowed to post answers quickly.Is it their gist or blog to document the changes..

Comment: @anishparajuli So you say that I'm correct in my assertion that it's harmful to wait, and the immediately say that people shouldn't be allowed to post answers quickly.  That's contradictory.  I'm specifically asserting that it's important that you *should* post the answer right away, if you already have it, and you agreed.

Comment: With release of swift 3..people are documenting some small changes in SO,is that fair enough..I agree with some full potential questions answering them is a right way to share knowledge

Comment: @anishparajuli You should evaluate the questions asked, and answer given, just as you would any non-self-answered question that might be asked, and any answer given by someone other than the author, determine how useful you feel the posts are, and vote on each accordingly.

Comment: what i think is, as user is not able to accept his own answer for 2 days..He/she should not be able to answer his own questions may be for 2 mins..thats all

Comment: @anishparajuli but... stack was meant to be a high level repository of knowledge, where each post ist meant to increase overall coding knowledge of future visitors. With that in mind, why is it not fair to do it? Yes it's a small change. If it's enough for users to google it and get the solution... Then it's likely to be beneficial to the community (as long as it's on-topic). You keep saying it's not fair... But why isn't it? Because it's an easy question? Doesn't really matter...